# Get all possible lines that contains a particular pattern

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I am attempting to use regular expression to get all lines that contains a particular word "authenticate(no)". My code segment is:

```
$pattern = "/^.*\bauthenticate\b.*$/m";
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

The output:

> array(1) { [0]=> string(54) " client.address=10.50.131.0/24
>   authenticate(no) " }

It brings me one single line which is the first line meets the condition. How to modify this to get all possible lines?

The text sample is as:

```
ALLOW client.address=Wireless-Guest-Segment limit_bandwidth.client.inbound(Guest) limit_bandwidth.server.outbound(Guest) access_log[main](yes) 


client.address=10.50.131.0/24 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.202.30 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.202.18 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.200.80 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.202.31 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.204.30 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.204.164 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.204.39 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.204.123 authenticate(no) 

client.address=10.50.130.5 authenticate(no) 

authenticate(integrated_windows_authenticatio) authenticate.force(no) authenticate.mode(auto)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `preg_match_all` instead to get all possible matches

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a regex to select lines that contains a literal string. `strpos` is the function to do that. And instead of splitting your data into lines or to make a pattern that describes a whole line, read your string or file line by line:

```
$handle = fopen("data:text/plain,$text", 'r'); // or fopen('/path/to/your/file', r);

$results = [];

while ( false !== $line = stream_get_line($handle, 1024, "\n") ) { // or "\r\n"
    if ( false !== strpos($line, 'authenticate(no)') )
        $results[] = $line;
}

print_r($results);
```

This way works for a string or a file. The advantage when it is a file is that the file content is never fully loaded into memory since it is read as a stream. Note that instead of storing the result in an array, you can continue in the same way ([lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)) and put the while loop into a generator that yields a result only when you need it, example:

```
$handle = fopen("data:text/plain,$text", 'r'); // or fopen('/path/to/your/file', r);

function getLine($handle, $filter) {
    while ( false !== $line = stream_get_line($handle, 1024, "\n") ) {
        if ( false !== strpos($line, $filter) )
             yield $line;
    }
}

foreach (getLine($handle, 'authenticate(no)') as $line) {
    echo $line, PHP_EOL;
}
```

But if for any reason you need the whole content to be loaded, you can use the `file` function that returns an array of lines and filter these lines with `array_filter` (or find them in a simple `foreach` loop):

```
$results = array_filter(file('/path/to/your/file'), function ($i) {
    return strpos($i, 'authenticate(no)') !== false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split the lines (assuming they are using a new line or return) then use a preg_grep.

```
$pattern = "/^.*\bauthenticate\b.*$/m";

$matches = preg_grep($pattern, preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $text));


var_dump($matches);
```

The above code would return any line with the text "authenticate"  The following code will only return lines with the text "authenticate(no).

```
$pattern = "/authenticate\(no\)/";

$matches = preg_grep($pattern, preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $text));

var_dump($matches);
```